# Is there any way to change the size of preallocate data file in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb data files are preallocates to a particular size,like first data file .0, the next .1, etc. The first file mongod allocates is 64 megabytes, the next 128 megabytes, and so on, up to 2 gigabytes, at which point all subsequent files are 2 gigabytes. Is there any way the default size can be change to 2GB? if so what will be the impact on the performance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify your own sizes, the only way to alter the sizes of data files is to specify (or not) the [smallfiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.smallFiles) option.  That will bring the file sizes down to 25% of the default (max of 512MB rather than 2GB etc.)

You can pre-allocate the files yourself in advance (with `dd`, [`fallocate`](https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/#fallocate) or similar).  I have a sample bash script using `fallocate` for just such a purpose [here on GitHub](https://github.com/comerford/mongodb-scripts/blob/master/pre_alloc.bash). You still have to do the progression of sizes up to 2GB first, then allocate the remainder at 2GB though.  If nothing else, full pre-allocation would let you determine if allocation is having any kind of impact on your testing.